# Is it possible to convert .vtk?

Tags: javascript, ruby, json, image-processing, vtk

i need to render vtks in webgl. can i transform them to a different type? or parse in JSON or sth. like that?

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you mean VTK (Visual Toolkit) image, I work with it. It is possible to convert the files from one to another format. Please, let me know if it is what you are looking for.

Comment: yes. that's correct! i tried using three.js but it cannot open .vtk. so i used **www.goxtk.com** instead.

Comment: What tool should I use to convert from VTK to STL? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this: http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/IO/ConvertFile to convert from (most) any type to (most) any other type.

Answer (score 0):

There's always [meshio](https://github.com/nschloe/meshio) (a project of mine). You can use it to convert unstructured VTK meshes to an array of other formats, e.g.,

```
meshio-convert mesh.vtk mesh.stl
```